# Structures contained in the .pdata section

Tags: windows, 64-bit, portable-executable

I need to read the ".pdata" section of a x64 PE file.
I've seen that the structures in the ".pdata"  section differ from one platform to another
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa448751.aspx
It also says the same thing in the PE specifications document.
But I dont understand what it is for the regular windows (XP/Vista/Win7 etc.)

Does anybody what it is?

Comment: Are you asking "What is the regular .pdata section format in a Windows executable?"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The *.pdata* section is an array of [RUNTIME_FUNCTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-runtime_function). It gives you a code range (first two members) and an RVA to the corresponding [UNWIND_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exception-handling-x64).

From there you get info like exception handler RVA, size of prolog, etc.

Comment: Your links no longer work. Im not sure what they pointed to, but here is information on the RUNTIME_FUNCTION structure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-runtime_function

Comment: Thanks, I edited it. Also updated the `UNWIND_INFO` link.