# Is it normal for C++Builder 64-bit Version to be 350MB and 32-bit Version 18MB?

Tags: c++builder

When I build my C++Builder 11.3 (FireDAC / SQLite) application for 32-bit it is about **18MB**, when I build the 64-bit version it's **350MB**

a) Linking with runtime packages is disabled for both 32-bit and 64-bit builds:

*Packages -> Runtime packages -> Link with runtime packages: [ ] false*

b) Linking with dynamic RTL is disabled for Release and enabled for Debug **but** changing the setting **does not** change the code size.

Release configuration - All platforms: *Building -> C++ linker -> Link with dynamic RTL*
**[ ] false**

Debug configuration - All Platforms:  *Building -> C++ linker -> Link with dynamic RTL [x] true*

I tried optimizing for smallest code, only reduced size a very small amount.

What is, or could be, making the 64-bit version so large and is that normal?

Here's what the **map file** shows for the release builds.

**64-bit:**

```
 Start Length Name Class
 0001:00401000 000BAB270H _TEXT                  CODE
 0002:00FAD000 000754A70H _RODATA                RODATA
 0003:01702000 0000614D0H _DATA                  DATA
 0004:017634D0 000049870H _BSS                   BSS
 0005:00000000 000000BB0H _TLS                   TLS
 0006:017AE000 013FD46CCH _PDATA                 PDATA
 0007:15783000 000183620H _XDATA                 XDATA
 0008:15907000 000000000H _DEBUG_ARANGES         DEBUG_ARANGES
 0009:15907000 000000000H _DEBUG_MACINFO         DEBUG_MACINFO
 0010:15907000 000000000H _DEBUG_PUBTYPES        DEBUG_PUBTYPES
 0011:15907000 000000000H _DEBUG_INFO            DEBUG_INFO
 0012:15907000 000000000H _DEBUG_ABBREV          DEBUG_ABBREV
 0013:15907000 000000000H _DEBUG_LINE            DEBUG_LINE
 0014:15907000 000000000H _DEBUG_ADDR            DEBUG_ADDR
 0015:15907000 000000000H _DEBUG_STR             DEBUG_STR
 0016:15907000 000000000H _DEBUG_LOC             DEBUG_LOC
 0017:15907000 000000000H _DEBUG_RANGES          DEBUG_RANGES
```

**32-bit:**

```
 Start Length Name Class
 0001:00401000 000B8DA00H _TEXT                  CODE
 0002:00F8F000 0001D5FB0H _DATA                  DATA
 0003:01164FB0 00002B43CH _BSS                   BSS
 0004:00000000 000000534H _TLS                   TLS
```

TIA!!

**Edit**

Looking at the file at offset **0x17AE000** looks like the most of the program, a bunch of tables/repeating data.

```
17A:DFC0h: –^.€—^.<«G.–^.  90 96 5E 00 80 97 5E 00 3C AB 47 15 90 96 5E 00 
17A:DFD0h: €—^.<«G.–^.€—^.  80 97 5E 00 3C AB 47 15 90 96 5E 00 80 97 5E 00 
17A:DFE0h: <«G.–^.€—^.<«G.  3C AB 47 15 90 96 5E 00 80 97 5E 00 3C AB 47 15 
17A:DFF0h: –^.€—^.<«G.–^.  90 96 5E 00 80 97 5E 00 3C AB 47 15 90 96 5E 00 
17A:E000h: €—^.<«G.–^.€—^.  80 97 5E 00 3C AB 47 15 90 96 5E 00 80 97 5E 00 
17A:E010h: <«G.–^.€—^.<«G.  3C AB 47 15 90 96 5E 00 80 97 5E 00 3C AB 47 15 
17A:E020h: –^.€—^.<«G.–^.  90 96 5E 00 80 97 5E 00 3C AB 47 15 90 96 5E 00 
17A:E030h: €—^.<«G.–^.€—^.  80 97 5E 00 3C AB 47 15 90 96 5E 00 80 97 5E 00 
17A:E040h: <«G.–^.€—^.<«G.  3C AB 47 15 90 96 5E 00 80 97 5E 00 3C AB 47 15 
17A:E050h: –^.€—^.<«G.–^.  90 96 5E 00 80 97 5E 00 3C AB 47 15 90 96 5E 00
```

Comment: I do not know much about CBuilder, but could it be that you are building a debug version with a lot of overhead instead of prod. version?

Comment: interesting question if I see it right `0006:017AE000 013FD46CCH _PDATA                 PDATA` is 319 MByte so you might start looking for what it actually holds ... so just view your exe or whatever as text and hex at address 017AE000h and look whats there maybe you recognize some strings in there to hint whats there ...

Comment: @EriksKlotins that was my first taught too but all the debug stuff has zero length in the map ...

Comment: Verify that debug information is disabled for the Release build: Project Options -> Building -> C++ Compiler -> Debugging

Comment: Debug is off.  Added dump - looks like a bunch of tables?  Most of the program looks like that, different patterns at times, but a bunch of duplicate stuff like that?

Comment: Are you building with debug info enabled, and if so are you building it into the EXE itself or into a separate TDS file? Also, what do you have "Link with the Delphi Runtime Library" set to in both cases?

Comment: @RemyLebeau - no it's off, the debug version is about 20M larger than the release.   The file is full of repeating garbage.  I tried various linker options, nothing mattered.  What does PDATA normally contain?

Comment: @user3161924 "*What does PDATA normally contain?*" - see [The .pdata Section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#the-pdata-section) on MSDN. It is used by the exception handling system in 64bit. Which seems to be corroborated (at least for Delphi) by [RAD Studio XE2 Overview | Changes in 64-bit Application Development | Exception handling](https://docs.devart.com/sdac/work-rad-studio-xe2.htm): "*The 64-bit compiler (dcc64.exe) ... generates [exception handling] metadata and stores it in the PDATA section of an executable file*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau But 300+MB seems a bit extreme. Would you agree?

Comment: @user3161924 that would be a good question to ask Embarcadero directly.  Here's some more info: [Structures contained in the .pdata section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794547/) It's a good amount of data per function/handler, so it could easily add up.

Comment: It is a known bug in C++Builder reported as far back as 10.4.  Caused by adding TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink or FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteWrapper.Stat.hpp  to the project.  Have to also not link with runtime packages (include them in the .exe)