# C++Builder - Link with only one runtime package - all the rest compiled in?

Tags: c++builder, firedac

x64 versions of C++Builder apps are 350+ MB when using SQLite, now 700+ MB with C++Builder 12 not fixing it. Having to use the `sIFDStatic` EngineLinkage, is there a way to just have that one lib as a `.dll`?

It's 350+ MB of an exception table, and with this new `sIFDStatic` to use the older SQLite, it appears to not exclude the new SQLite, but link both in somehow.

I presume the runtime package is `FireDACSqliteDriver`. So, if I can external link with just that one, I can hopefully work around this issue.

However, I don't see an option to exclude in project settings, it's `Link with Runtime Packages` on or off.

Comment: this reminds me on another [question about x64 C++Builder exe size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76777059/2521214) ... see the (last) comments in there its related to a known bug ...

Answer (score 0):

From Support: This works for standard/latest version sqlite, but not if you need FDE.

1. There are two files in $(BDS)\source\data\firedac that are required.
2. Make "FireDAC.inc" writeable.
3. Open the file in an editor and search for "{.$UNDEF
   FireDAC_SQLITE_STATIC}"
4. Remove the period aka "."
5. Add the "FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteWrapper.Stat.pas" to your project and
   build.